# Read all directories and check it meets the criteria

Tags: batch-file

I was looking for a bit of help.

I want to read a dir (c:\test)
and all dir's in here if they are only 2 digits (only one deep) should be checked for a sub dir (temp) and if not there then create it.

So 
c:\test\hello... leave (as dir world is more than 2 characters)
c:\test\AA - in here check for temp - if not there then create
c:\test\world... leave (as dir world is more than 2 characters)
c:\test\BB - in here check for temp - if not there then create

I have tried multiple ways but I always seem to fail when I try to check the folder name/string length.

Hope someone can help or give me a start
Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Easy way...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "alphabet=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
FOR %%a IN (%alphabet%) DO FOR %%b IN (%alphabet%) DO IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%a%%b\." ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%%a%%b\temp" 2>nul
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `destdir` to suit your circumstances and extend the string assigned to `alphabet` as appropriate.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. The `2>nul` appended to the MD command suppresses error messages (eg. when the "new" directory already exists)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "target=c:\test"
    >nul 2>nul (
        for /f %%a in ('
            dir /ad /b "%target%\??" ^| findstr /r /c:"^..$"
        ') do md "%target%\%%a\temp"
    )
```

Use a `dir` command to retrieve the list of one or two character folders. Filter the list with `findstr` to only keep the folder with two characters. For each folder in the final list, directly try to create the `temp` folder.